# scraping : scraping second level of url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

In the below code parse function executes approximately 32 times (foor loop 32 href's found) in the sameway each sublink should go and scrape the data(32 individual urls **parse_next** function)
.But **parse_next** function executes only once(one way)/not called(  and output csv file is empty.can anyone help me where i did mistake.

```
import scrapy
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('mycustomlogger')

from ScrapyTestProject.items import ScrapytestprojectItem
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nestedurl"
    allowed_domains = ['www.grohe.in']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.grohe.com/in/7780/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/',
def parse(self, response):
    logger.info("Parse function called on %s", response.url)
    for divs in response.css('div.viewport div.workspace div.float-box'):
        item = {'producturl': divs.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
                'imageurl': divs.css('a img::attr(src)').extract_first(),
                'description' : divs.css('a div.text::text').extract() + divs.css('a span.nowrap::text').extract()}
        next_page = response.urljoin(item['producturl'])
        #logger.info("This is an information %s", next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_next, meta={'item': item})
        #yield item

def parse_next(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    logger.info("Parse function called on2 %s", response.url)
    item['headline'] = response.css('div#content a.headline::text').extract()
    return item
    #response.css('div#product-variants a::attr(href)').extract()
```

Comment: Checked your for loop and should work properly. Therefore there should be some sort of error in your logs. Did you try to run the spider with a DEBUG log level? This should give you some indication where stuff is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few things go wrong:

- Indentation
- start_urls list is not closed with a [
- allowed_domains uses the domain extension .in while you want to scrape .com

Working code below:

```
import scrapy
import logging

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nestedurl"
    allowed_domains = ['www.grohe.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.grohe.com/in/7780/bathroom/bathroom-faucets/essence/'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        # logger.info("Parse function called on %s", response.url)
        for divs in response.css('div.viewport div.workspace div.float-box'):
            item = {'producturl': divs.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
                    'imageurl': divs.css('a img::attr(src)').extract_first(),
                    'description' : divs.css('a div.text::text').extract() + divs.css('a span.nowrap::text').extract()}
            next_page = response.urljoin(item['producturl'])
            #logger.info("This is an information %s", next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_next, meta={'item': item})
            #yield item

    def parse_next(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        # logger.info("Parse function called on2 %s", response.url)
        item['headline'] = response.css('div#content a.headline::text').extract()
        return item
        #response.css('div#product-variants a::attr(href)').extract()
```

Note: deleted some logging / item pipelines as these are not defined on my machine.

Comment: Thanks.if i comment **allowed_domains** it is working. I have huge list of URLs. Every url page contains their own way of HTML presentation for browser.

How can i write a normalized script to traverse the HTML of those listing web page URLs and scrap the data irrespective of the format.